# Security folder permissions for service account

Tags: file-permissions, files-folders

I wrote a script to add the security to permissions to the folder and inside the subfolders, but and granted the full permission for that user.

When i run the script it is adding the user to the sub folder **i want it add to the root folder, sub folder and to the files inside that sub folder with the full right permissions and also to enable the inheritance for that user**

```
# Set properties
$identity = "ANC_C"
$fileSystemRights = "FullControl"
$type = "Allow"

$allFolders=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Work\Test -Directory -Recurse

foreach ($Folder in $allFolders){

$fileSystemAccessRuleArgumentList = $identity, $fileSystemRights, $type
$fileSystemAccessRule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $fileSystemAccessRuleArgumentList

$Permission=get-acl -Path $Folder.FullName
$Permission.SetAccessRule($fileSystemAccessRule)
Set-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName -AclObject $Permission
}
```

**Folder Structure**
I have the folder Structure as below:
[image]

**Thanks In Advance**

Answer (score 0):

The legacy cmdlet Get-Acl, Set-Acl are not very comprehensive and easy to use. Culd I suggest to use the Powershell Module called NTFSSecurity.

````
$Root = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp"
Add-NTFSAccess -Path $Root -Account <Domain\AccountName -AccessRights FullControl 
<#
Other parameters 
-AccessType : values (Allow/block) - Default value Allow, then you can ommit it
-AppliesTo ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles or other (see the parameterValueSet), this one is the default, you can ommit it
-PropagationFlags is InheritOnly as a default value, you can ommit it. 
-PassThru : useful to see the output in the console. 

```
One cmdlet to do the job. Definitivly adopted !
Hope this help
Olivier
````